# Can't compile CGAL code

Tags: c++, cgal

I can't compile this code from [CGAL docs](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Triangulation_2/Triangulation_2_2constrained_plus_8cpp-example.html#_a3), got the following error:

```
$ g++ apply.cpp -lCGAL -I/usr/local/include -o a.out
In file included from /usr/include/CGAL/Constrained_triangulation_2.h:28:0,
                 from /usr/include/CGAL/Constrained_Delaunay_triangulation_2.h:25,
                 from apply.cpp:3:
/usr/include/CGAL/Triangulation_2.h: In instantiation of ‘class CGAL::Triangulation_2<CGAL::Epeck, CGAL::Default>’:
/usr/include/CGAL/Constrained_triangulation_2.h:47:7:   required from ‘class CGAL::Constrained_triangulation_2<CGAL::Epeck, CGAL::Default, CGAL::Exact_intersections_tag>’
/usr/include/CGAL/Constrained_Delaunay_triangulation_2.h:63:7:   required from ‘class CGAL::Constrained_Delaunay_triangulation_2<CGAL::Epeck, CGAL::Default, CGAL::Exact_intersections_tag>’
/usr/include/CGAL/Constrained_triangulation_plus_2.h:64:7:   required from ‘class CGAL::Constrained_triangulation_plus_2<CGAL::Constrained_Delaunay_triangulation_2<CGAL::Epeck, CGAL::Default, CGAL::Exact_intersections_tag> >’
apply.cpp:12:16:   required from here
/usr/include/CGAL/Triangulation_2.h:100:48: error: no type named ‘size_type’ in ‘struct CGAL::Default’
```

I installed libcgal-dev, libcgal-demo, g++ and cmake from apt.
G++ version 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9

Comment: That's a strange error indeed, because `size_type` is defined in `Triangulation_2.h`. I'm sorry I can't help more, but if you look into that file you might see what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C/C++ isn't clear about version errors, this code example is from CGAL 4.12, my library was 4.7.

I had to upgrade my linux for 18.04 to get a recent libboost version in a stable way, then I used the libcgal 4.11 from [the official repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libcgal&searchon=names&suite=bionic&section=all) for less overhead compiling and maintaining the library.

Comment: please cite here the versions you ended up using